# Perl pp utility locale problems

Tags: perl

i am trying  to use pp utility from PAR package to create an exe file of my Perl program on windows
eg

```
pp -o script.exe script.pl
```

The command runs ok, but when i try to run the exe, it gives me

```
The locale codeset (cp1252) isn't one that perl can decode, stopped at Encode/Locale.pm  line 94. Compilation failed in require at LWP/UserAgent.pm line 1000.
```

What could be the problem? I have a list of modules being used in the script, these include, Cwd, LWP::Simple, LWP::Useragent , Win32::OLE.

enviroment:

```
1) windows vista
2) Activestate Perl 5.16
3) did not manage to install PAR::Packager successfully, unless i use "force" install, which manage to install.
```

thanks

Comment: Does script.pl work correctly when you don't pack it first?

Comment: yes. it is able to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Encode::Locale` finds the modules it needs to decode various encodings in a way that `pp` can't discover automatically. You'll need to tell `pp` which additional modules are required.

This should do the trick:

```
pp -m Encode::Byte -o script.exe script.pl
```